# How to install docker-ce? for version 18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian

Tags: docker, debian

In the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/), it mentions to run command:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=<VERSION_STRING> docker-ce-cli=<VERSION_STRING> containerd.io
```

---

But I think this command is for latest version of packages in this list:

```
$ apt-cache madison docker-ce
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.5~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.4~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.3~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.2~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.1~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:19.03.0~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.9~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.8~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.7~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.6~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.5~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.4~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.3~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.2~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.1~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 5:18.09.0~3-0~debian-stretch | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.06.3~ce~3-0~debian | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.06.2~ce~3-0~debian | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.06.0~ce~3-0~debian | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.03.1~ce-0~debian | https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch/stable amd64 Packages
```

---

I would like to install package `18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian` for `18.06.1` version of docker. Using above syntx:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian docker-ce-cli=18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian containerd.io
```

gives below error:

```
   E: Version '18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian' for 'docker-ce-cli' was not found
```

---

What is the right syntax to install docker-ce?

Comment: did you try to install it from the package? Find your Debian distro [here](https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/) (probably you have to look in the "pool" directory) and install via `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb`

Comment: @Berger I know nothing about apt package manager and debian.. please let me know the command to run..

Comment: well, I posted the command :D which Debian version do you have? Buster, Jessie, Stretch, Wheezy? architechture I guess amd64

Comment: @Berger it looks like Debian stretch... Because `apt-cache madison docker-ce` gives above output shown in query. Why docker documentation does not specify your syntax?

Comment: Just saw it... Then download [this](https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian_amd64.deb) package and then run the command `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/docker-ce_18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian_amd64.deb`

Comment: @Berger I have to add this command in `Dockerfile`. `apt-get -y install docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian` Is this fine?

Comment: If it installs yes... you should be also able to use apt to install .deb packages. If it doesn't work use `sudo apt install /path/to/package/name.deb` see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt) for background information

Comment: Did it work now?

Comment: @Berger It worked with `apt-get -y install docker-ce=${DOCKER_VERSION:-18.06.1~ce~3-0~debian}` in Dockerfile. But am expecting documentation to be done on this, [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/). We don't rely on debian references etc... and not interested to learn, what debian is? what stretch is?

Comment: That's right. On the upper right hand corner you can click on "edit this page" or "request docs change" :)

Comment: @Berger debian distribution team should update this [page](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/). Ubuntu distribution team should take care of this [page](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/). I have nothing to do with this...in maintaining this page. Because I don't know, the meaning of .. `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb`.